# Some applications open in low resolution

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, resolution

Some applications, like Unity3D (but not limited to it) open in too low resolution:

[image]

The flag "open in low resolution" is not set:

[image]

Also, from time to time, menu bar apps are also displayed in a low resolution:

[image]

Here's my Mac system information:

[image]

Is there any way to make them displayed in a good resolution?

Comment: I've seen that bug with menu extras before – if you change the display resolution (to anything other setting, doesn't matter which) and then change it back, it'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retina must be supported by the app for it to be displayed in Retina. If the app does not support Retina then the app will not be displayed in Retina.

You may be able to force Retina for an app with [**Retinizer**](http://retinizer.mikelpr.com):

> [image]
>
> **Retinizer** is a small app I wrote that **allows apps that aren’t retina** ready and are displayed pixelated at 1x **to display** their UI widgets **at 2x**. That way, only their custom images will look bad and not the whole app.

Comment: Unfortunately, this app doesn't work in case of Unity3D. No changes at all.

Comment: @user3895471 You will then need to wait for an update to the software by the developers.

Comment: It seems you're right... I've just read their twitter and forums - they don't support retina display yet.