# Font on Unity Application doesn't smooth

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, font

I'm using Mac book pro 13 inches with retina display. I see that on retina screen, font is smooth, and in almost applications, I see font is always smooth, too but not in Unity. I'm currently using Unity 4.6 free edition and Mac OS X Maverick version.

I have uploaded an image demo. As you see, font in taskbar, title bar is smooth, but font inside unity doesn't. I have watched some demos online using unity too and I see their font screen is smooth, not as I am.

Please explain for me why and how can I fix this.

Thanks :)

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retina must be supported by the app for it to be displayed in Retina. If the app does not support Retina then the app will not be displayed in Retina.

You may be able to force Retina for an app with [**Retinizer**](http://retinizer.mikelpr.com):

> [image]
>
> **Retinizer** is a small app I wrote that **allows apps that aren’t retina** ready and are displayed pixelated at 1x **to display** their UI widgets **at 2x**. That way, only their custom images will look bad and not the whole app.

Related: [Some applications open in low resolution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141934/some-applications-open-in-low-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

You can add key to the `Info.plist` file from this app. It's located inside app bundle, for example:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist`

The key which needs to be added is:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key> 
<string>True</string>
```

NOTE: make a copy of Your app first, so that You won't break anything.

Comment: sorry :( I have tried. but seem no change :(

Comment: You can try to reboot Your Mac or rebuild Launch Services ( http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/126526/74657 ).

Answer (score 0):

You can add key to the Info.plist file from this app. It's located inside app bundle, for example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

The key which needs to be added is:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key> 
<string>True</string>
```